# .profile in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, .profile

I have set my terminal preferences to execute:

```
 set -o vi
```

at startup. The problem is I don't get that command executed when open a new terminal tab.

Is there something like .profile in OS X where I can put that command?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `.profile` file in MacOSX works exactly how you would expect.
Simply create the .profile file in your user directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ooohhh!!! Thank you. I got confused by the fact it wasn't there. I've create it and runs perfectly. Years ago OXS used tcsh, do you know which one is used currently? bash I guess?

Comment: Yes, by default Terminal uses bash.

Comment: does profile require `#!/bin/bash` header?

Answer (score 12):

Because, as noted, Terminal has used bash by default for a few versions, you may want to keep an eye out for a .bash_profile file if .profile isn't present. See the "which startup files are read by the shell?" FAQ at http://hayne.net/MacDev/Notes/unixFAQ.html#shellStartup which explain how the different files are used and the order in which they're read at startup.