# OS-X download, "Add the following statements to your .profile file: " EGSnrc download

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have nearly configured EGSnrc on my OS-X machine running el capitan

### The final step is the following....

The EGSnrc configuration for NAME is ALMOST complete ...

EGSnrc requires various environment variables and aliases to be defined.
Typically you add these definitions to your shell resource file located in
your home directory, to ensure the EGSnrc environment is properly set up
every time you log in.

Your default shell is /bin/bash

### Add the following statements to your .profile file

However I cannot find such a file? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.profile in Mac OS X?](http://superuser.com/questions/1031/profile-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's the duplicate  of [.profile in Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/1031/profile-in-mac-os-x)
.profile should be placed in your home directory.

The easiest way to edit it or place if it's not added is through terminal:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

CTRL+X will ask if you want to save your file and exit.